# Let $f\in L^2(0,2\pi)$ and $|x(n)| \leq C(1+|n|)^{-k-2}$ for all n then $f \in C^k(0, 2\pi)$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(0,2\pi)$ and $|x(n)| \leq C(1+|n|)^{-k-2}$ for all n then $f \in C^k(0, 2\pi)$ where $x(n)$ is a fourier coefficient.

Ive tried to show that a fourier series partial sums converges  which are cts converges uniformly, but without any result. Any ideas?

Comment: How can you consider $(n-1)$-th derivative if you need to prove that $f\in C^k$?

Comment: oops i mixed with my notation, but i fixed the issue.

Comment: This is a special case of Proposition 3.3.12 in the book *Classical Fourier Analysis* by Loukas Grafakos, third edition. Pick $n=1, s=k+1$. The result also holds for all $f\in L^1([0,2\pi])$.